# Can I include/extend a module but mark all included/extended methods as private?

Tags: ruby, module

Say, I have a class `A` and a module `B`. I'd want to include/extend `B` into `A` but mark included/extended methods as private (so they won't be accessible to callers of `A` but will be accessible inside methods of `A`).

How can I include `B` into `A` but mark all included methods as private?

Comment: Maybe this is a job better suited to delegation / composition rather than inheritance?

Comment: @RonDahlgren Could you elaborate or provide or link to what you propose?

Comment: Delegation is a design pattern that involves holding an internal instance of B (the delegate). Methods you'd like to expose should be written as methods of A, where the implementation just calls ("delegates") to the internal instance of B. Composition is a less specific form of delegation, where a particular behavior is made by 'compositing' instances of different, disparate classes. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Comment: (Delta the notion of "privacy" in Ruby, I assume.)

Comment: @RonDahlgren Currently I include B not only to A but also to C, D, E. If I'll remove B from my code and put methods that are in B to A, then it won't be possible to use those methods in other classes(C, D, E)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the term 'include' in your question and your previous comment. In terms of a class hierarchy, are you saying that B is a superclass of A, C, D, and E?

Comment: I see - it seems that include and extend are both essentially mechanisms for performing inheritance, each with slightly different results. With that being said, perhaps it would make sense to have a single delegate wrapper that sets up the visibility rules you want, then include this delegate class in the A,C,D,and E classes you mention above? I'm not too savvy on the visibility modifications the answer below mentions :-/

Comment: @RonDahlgren I mean [this include](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/1133877859/include-vs-extend). If A (or C, or D, or E) includes B, then B will be in ancestors chain of A (or C, or D, or E) (but it won't be a superclass as it's a module, not class)

Answer (score 6):

Include and then explicitly make all included methods private?

```rb
class A
  include B
  private *B.instance_methods
  extend B
  class << self
    private *B.instance_methods
  end
end
```

You can monkey patch `Module` to add `private_include` and `private_extend`:

```rb
class Module
  def private_include *modules
    class_eval do
      self.send(:include, *modules)
      modules.each do |mod|
        self.send(:private, *mod.instance_methods)
      end
    end
  end

  def private_extend *modules
    singleton = class << self; self end
    singleton.instance_eval do
      self.send(:include, *modules)
      modules.each do |mod|
        self.send(:private, *mod.instance_methods)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a really good monkeypatch to answer the question.  Bravo.